# Exception Handler works only when run from within Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I'm creating a `Windows Forms` application using Visual Studio 2012, C#, .NET 4.5; Windows 7.

I would like to handle any unhandled exception with my own error handler. I wrote some code like the own shown below. I even tried two different ways of error handling.

Now when I run this program within Visual Studio (2012), then this works very fine !

But when I start the program from explorer, then my error handler is never called; instead, there will always pop up the standard error handler from .NET Framework.

So what am I doing wrong?

```
static void Main()
{
    try
    {
        AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
        currentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(HandleUnhandledException);
        Application.Run(new frmMainFrame());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Here is my error handler ....
    }
}

static void HandleUnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs args) 
{
    Exception ex = (Exception) args.ExceptionObject;
    // Here is my error handler ....
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hook up [Application.ThreadException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception.aspx) as well.

Or set [Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.setunhandledexceptionmode.aspx) to [UnhandledExceptionMode.ThrowException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.unhandledexceptionmode.aspx) to have your appdomain handler kickin.

Comment: Yes, that worked !

Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.ThrowException);

Seems that Visual Studio sets this mode by default, while explorer does not. Thanks !!

Comment: @Giosco: Explorer has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @siride - can you explain this more further? As far as I understand it now, the starting environment sets the UnhandledExceptionMode, and Visual Studio and Explorer seem to do this differently.

Comment: @Giosco: Explorer doesn't know or care that the app is a .NET app. From its point of view, your app is just another PE executable. Are you using the vshost helper task? It's the default. My guess is that it has something to do with why this gets set, but it's possible the debugger also forces the issue since it has the power.

Answer (score 0):

First at all i would use the `Debugger.Break()` Method to attach your program into to problematic code part. Than maybe just check if currentDomain is not null. Assumed that you don't raise a Exception that forces the CLI to stop.